# When open the files and assignment to char ,Incompatible Types error

Tags: c

I'm trying to find sum of large numbers.(100-digit,1500-digit)

There is my sum function:

```
char *find_sum(char *a, char *b) {
  char *res;
  int alen, blen, rlen;
  int carry;

  alen = strlen(a);
  blen = strlen(b);
  rlen = 1 + ((alen > blen) ? alen : blen);
  res = malloc(1 + rlen);
  if (res) {
    int oldlen = rlen;
    res[rlen] = 0;
    carry = 0;
    while (rlen) {
      int tmp;
      if (alen && blen) tmp = a[--alen] - '0' + b[--blen] - '0';
      else if (alen) tmp = a[--alen] - '0';
      else if (blen) tmp = b[--blen] - '0';
      else tmp = 0;
      tmp += carry;
      res[--rlen] = '0' + tmp % 10;
      carry = tmp / 10;
    }
    if (res[0] == '0') memmove(res, res+1, oldlen);
  }
  return res;
}
```

If I'm try to like below, code is working:

```
char a[] = "243432423423423";
char b[] = "74356348775345";
char *c;
c = find_sum(a,b);
printf("%s",c);
```

But I want to these numbers(a and b) get from a file(by line).For example my data.txt has below lines:

```
7326473264723672364723864762374236
32473264623748632784632784
432423432423423423
0
3248972389473289473289478923
4897238473247382
732468723647236478238423
0
432748932489327894723894798239
48327489237483278
0
32423423423423
```

I want to open this file, read each line and sum of all numbers(stopped if reach 0 and write other file sum.txt)

If I try to addition values from files using **fgets**, I take the incompatible types error.

My testing code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *find_sum(char *a, char *b);

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("a.txt", "r");

    if (file != NULL){
        char *buf;
        char *buf1;
    char *sum;
        fgets(buf, 100, file);
        fgets(buf1, 100, file);

        sum = find_sum(buf, buf1);

        printf("%s",sum);

    }
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
char *find_sum(char *a, char *b) {
  char *res;
  int alen, blen, rlen;
  int carry;

  alen = strlen(a);
  blen = strlen(b);
  rlen = 1 + ((alen > blen) ? alen : blen);
  res = malloc(1 + rlen);
  if (res) {
    int oldlen = rlen;
    res[rlen] = 0;
    carry = 0;
    while (rlen) {
      int tmp;
      if (alen && blen) tmp = a[--alen] - '0' + b[--blen] - '0';
      else if (alen) tmp = a[--alen] - '0';
      else if (blen) tmp = b[--blen] - '0';
      else tmp = 0;
      tmp += carry;
      res[--rlen] = '0' + tmp % 10;
      carry = tmp / 10;
    }
    if (res[0] == '0') memmove(res, res+1, oldlen);
  }
  return res;
}
```

Comment: If you have a compiler error it usually helps to actually post the offending portion of the code .

Comment: Posting the code you got working is not so helpful if you want us to solve your problem.

Comment: at witch line of your code you get the error? btw you don't allocate memory for `buf` and `buf1` and `fclose(file)` needs to be inside `if(file != NULL){...}` as the last line of that block.

Comment: You say you're getting an "incompatible types" error, which is a compile-time error. The code you've posted compiles without error. Show us the code that fails to compile, show us the error messages, and tell us which line the error message refers to.

Comment: If I use to like char *buf = malloc(100); code is working.But return the like 3242*** or 2466**%+ values.(I'm sorry I forget use malloc above code)

Comment: Note that you are getting the error because you are compiling this as C++ code, not C.  In C, a `void*` can be implicitly converted to any pointer type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gess you are gettign this error

```
36 D:\Projects\c_c++\so\find_sum\main.cpp invalid conversion from `void*' to `char*'
```

at the line

```
res = malloc(1 + rlen);
```

`malloc` returns `void*` witch yo need to cast to the type for witch you are allocating the memory. to get rid of this error add a type cats this way

```
  res = (char*) malloc(1 + rlen);
```

your code will compile then.

**EDIT**

Read numbers from file and write result of addition to another output file

Basically you will need to that in a loop, read two operands and make the addition, since you have to stop adding only after you have found a line containing a `"0"` or you have reached `EOF`, you'll have to read the next operand in the next loop and add the sum from previous loop to it then store the result back to the sum. after you have reached `"0"` or `EOF` write the file sum to the output file.

an other alternative would be to read all numbers into an array of strings till you reach `"0"` or `EOF` in one step, an in the next step you iterate over all numbers red, compute the sum and then write it to the output file.

here is a sample implementation for the first solution

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    char buf[100] = "";    
    FILE *input_file = fopen("a.txt", "r");

    if (input_file) {
        FILE *output_file = fopen("r.txt", "w");
        if(output_file) {
            char *op1 = NULL, *op2 = NULL, *sum = NULL, *p_buf = NULL;

            do {
                // if we alredy have done an additin, copy (flat) that result to op1
                if(sum) {
                    printf("have sum %s\n", sum);
                    op1 = sum;
                }
                // if op1 does not point to a sum from previous addition, then attemp to read it from file
                if(! op1) { 
                    // read next operand and escape all "0"
                    do {
                        p_buf = fgets(buf, 100, input_file);
                        remove_new_line_ending(p_buf, buf);
                    } while(p_buf && 0 == strcmp(p_buf, "0"));

                    if(p_buf) {
                         printf("read op1 %s\n", buf);
                         op1 = strdup(buf);
                         sum = op1;
                    }
                }

                // read next operand
                p_buf = fgets(buf, 100, input_file);
                remove_new_line_ending(p_buf, buf);
                if(p_buf && 0 != strcmp(p_buf, "0")) {
                    printf("read op2 %s\n", buf);
                     op2 = strdup(buf);
                }

                // we have both op1 and op2 then make the addition
                if(op1 && op2) {
                    printf("have op1 and op2 %s\n", "");
                    sum = find_sum(op1, op2);
                } else {
                    if(sum) {
                        // if we have only op1 then it is the result from the previous addion and there is no operand left in the file
                        // then write the result to output file and reset all variables
                        printf("print sum %s to output file\n\n", sum);
                        fprintf(output_file, "%s\n0\n", sum);
                        free(sum);
                        sum = NULL;
                    }
                }
                free(op1);
                free(op2);
                op1 = NULL;
                op2 = NULL;

            } while(p_buf);

            fclose(output_file);

        } else {
            perror("r.txt");
        }

        fclose(input_file);
    } else {
        perror("a.txt");
    }

    return 0;
}

void remove_new_line_ending(char* line, char dest[])
{
     if(line) {
         int len = strlen(line);
         int i = 0;
         while(i < len && line[i] != '\r' && line[i] != '\n') {
             dest[i] = line[i];
             i++;
         }
         dest[i] = '\0';
     }
}
```

**Input**

```
0
0
7326473264723672364723864762374236
32473264623748632784632784
432423432423423423
0
0
0
3248972389473289473289478923
4897238473247382
732468723647236478238423
0
0
432748932489327894723894798239
48327489237483278
0
32423423423423
0
0
```

**Output**

```
7326473297196937420895929970430443
0
3249704858201833948240964728
0
432748932489376222213132281517
0
32423423423423
0
```

Comment: char *num1 = malloc(100);
char *num2 = malloc(100);
char *sum = malloc(100);
fgets(num1, 100, file);
fgets(num2, 100, file);

sum = find_sum(num1,num2);

sum return bad values.

Comment: maybe fgets return "321312\n" ?

Comment: Yes `fgets()` stores the line ending char/char-sequence at the end of the string. line ending might be `\r\n` if on widnows.

Comment: Yess.I removed '\n' character.But,I have a problem.I want to open file(like above 21312321\n2132132\n0\n4334) I want to write sum of all numbers to new file if reach 0.How?

Comment: I would note that the cast is only needed because the OP is using a C++ compiler. In C you should *never* cast the return value of `malloc`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, didn't know that before, it was just a coincidence that i've built the source using dev-cpp witch defaults to g++ and then got the error. Thanks for pointing that.

Comment: this code is working perfectly.But if I add to three zero sub-bottom I take the core dumped error.(like 213213 1231 0 12312 0 0 0 21321 0)

Comment: basically you'll have to read all `"0"` till you reach something tha might be `op1`. `op2` has to come directly after `op1` otherweis `op1` is your sume. I've update the main method, take a look at the `do {...} while(...);` loop for reading `op1`.

Comment: the code is not well tested, its first goal is to show how you can do it. you'll have to debug it a little bit and find out what might go wrong ... good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your variables at the beginning of the main function (not inside a conditional), and you must allocate memory to them.  The easiest way to do this would be to declare them as

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    char buf[100];
    char buf1[100];
```

Comment: why not inside `if(file){ ... }` ? what if the file does not exist ? and `fopen()` returned NULL ? the memory will be allocated for free! a good practice is to allocate memory for a variable right before needing it.